# Set a MapIcon Image by reference

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to set a MapControl MapIcon Image by reference?

That should allow to modify the referenced Image modifying in one single operation all MapIcon using the same reference.

In example, I'd like to do something like this (that not works) to assign the icon image by reference:

```
    Uri BluePinUri = new URI ("ms-appx:///Assets/blue_pin.png");
    private IRandomAccessStreamReference BluePin = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(BluePinUri);
    
    MapIcon NewMapIcon = new MapIcon
                {
                    Location = myLocation,
                    Title = myTitle,
                    (ref) Image = (ref) BluePin
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there is no way to do that. Besides, the MapIcon doesn't have a setbinding method so we could not use data binding as well. A possible way is to use a foreach loop to get all the MapIcon controls and modify the image.